# Copy row if cell is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have a raw datasheet in the first tab with Invoice numbers and a cell next to it stating if they have (quarter number and year)/ haven't been paid (empty cell).

I want to copy the unpaid invoice numbers (or even better the whole row) to second sheet.

Because there are couple thousand rows, I can't use an if statement and then sort and delete the rows that have been paid.

Is there a way to show only the wanted information?

Comment: Based on the information you provided, you shouldn't need any VBA at all; you can use Excel's data filtering capabilities, and copy and paste the filtered results. Therefore, I think your question isn't really a good fit for StackOverflow, which is about programming questions; and it's unclear why your question is a programming question.

Comment: Yes, but it's nice to automate the task if it is repeated as a periodic routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the following structure starting from `A1` (worksheet `Orig`)

[image: Origin]

The following generic commented code solve the problem:

```
Sub CopyInv()
 Dim O As Worksheet 
 Dim D As Worksheet
 Set O = Worksheets("Orig") 
 Set D = Worksheets("Dest")
 Dim CF As Integer ' Last column
 Dim LD As Long ' Last line in destination
 Dim LO As Long ' Last line filled
 Dim LOF As Long ' Last line in origin
' Final table colunm in source
 CF = O.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
' Last line with data in destination (emulate ^Up)
 LD = D.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 Range(D.Cells(1, 1), D.Cells(LD, CF - 1)).Clear
 O.Select
' Sort by 3rd column
 O.Cells(1, 3).Sort key1:=O.Cells(1, 3), 
                Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes 
 Cells(1, 1).Select
' Last filled data in "paid" column
 LO = O.Cells(1, 3).End(xlDown).Row + 1
' Last line in origin
 LOF = O.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  ' Copy header in destination
 Range(O.Cells(1, 1), O.Cells(1, 2)).Copy (D.Cells(1, 1))  
 If LOF >= LO Then   ' Copy in destination
   Range(O.Cells(LO, 1), O.Cells(LOF, 2)).Copy (D.Cells(2, 1)) 
 End If
 D.Select
 Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

The result in destination (worksheet `Dest`) starting from `A1` is:

[image: Destination]